# sed: insert a macro with backslashes and newlines before a line in a file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have text in a file like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MIN 0
#define MAX 100
```

I want to insert a macro before the 1st #define like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MAXIMUM(a,b) \ 
(a>b?(return a):(return b))
#define MIN 0
#define MAX 100
```

I tried my luck with sed, but it wasn't so successful. I have to do this in a bash script, say add_macro.sh, which is executed as:

```
./add_macro file.c
```

and contains:

```
var1="#define"
var2="#define MAXIMUM(a,b) \ /\n(a>b?(return a):(return b))"
sed "H;${x;s/$var1 .*\n/$var2&/;p;}" $1 > $1.tmp
```

When I run the above script, it does something like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MIN 0
#define MAX 100


#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MAXIMUM(a,b)          //no '\' is printed
(a>b?(return a):(return b))
#define MIN 0
#define MAX 100
```

It repeats the data and does substitution only once.
Any help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:

```
var2='#define MAXIMUM(a,b) \\\n(a>b?(return a):(return b))'
var1='#define'
sed "H; 0,/^$var1 .*/s//$var2\n&/1;" $1 > $1.tmp
```

Thanks everyone for the input!

Answer (score 1):

```
var1="#define"
var2='#define MAXIMUM(a,b) \\ \
    (a>b?(return a):(return b))'
sed "0,/^$var1/{/^$var1/s/$var1/$var2\n$var1/}" $1
```

or a bit shorter:

```
sed "0,/^$var1/s/^$var1/$var2\n$var1/" $1
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but it doesn't work if the 1st occurence of a #define is in a comment. For eg,
....
// #defines are defined in this file..bla bla bla
..
#define MAX 100..

Comment: edited to handle `//` comments, but with `/*` comments, I don't know :)

Comment: I have posted a solution, that checks the 1st character should be a "#", followed by "define".

Answer (score 0):

```
var1="#define MIN"
var2="#define MAXIMUM(a,b) \\\\ \n(a>b?(return a):(return b))"
sed "s/${var1}.*$/$var2\n&/g;" $1 > $1.tmp
```

Comment: your solution repeats the lines. I have posted a solution that works fine.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simpler pattern:

```
var1="#define MIN 0"
var2="#define MAXIMUM(a,b) \\\\\n(a>b?(return a):(return b))"
cat test.c |sed "s%^\($var1\)$%$var2\n\1%g"
```

You get:

```
samveen@precise:/tmp$ bash replace.sh
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MAXIMUM(a,b) \
(a>b?(return a):(return b))
#define MIN 0
#define MAX 100
```

This also ensures that it'll replace only those lines that match just the exact contents of `var1`, ensured by the `^` and `$` anchors in the pattern.

Comment: @perreal My understanding is that he wants to match the first define statement in the example program, which is `^#define MIN 0$`. In case he wants to do this on the first `^#define` instead, then you have the correct answer :).

Comment: Yes. I want to match just the 1st occurrence. Apologize for the confusion! :)